# NSIS and reading from XML on uninstall

Tags: java, windows, nsis

I create a Windows installation package of my Java (Swing) application with NSIS tool.

After installation when a user starts an application it creates a temporary 
"work" folder in the "**user.dir**" directory using a user-customized name as the directory name. The full path of this folder is saved to an XML file in "**user.dir"/Corp/configuration.xml** file.

This folder might contain gigabytes of data (depending on user activity).

This is important to delete this directory if a user decides to uninstall the application using NSIS standard "uninstall".

The question I would like to ask respected SO people is:

HOW CAN I READ AN XML FILE IN NSIS FROM "user.dir" FOLDER TO GET A FOLDER PATH AND DELETE IT?

This is an extract from my script file to do "uninstall" procedure:

```
Section "Uninstall"

  ;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...

  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

  RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"

  !insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_GETFOLDER Application $StartMenuFolder

  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuFolder\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuFolder\Corp MyApp.lnk"

  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuFolder"

  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Corp\MyApp"

SectionEnd
```

Thank you for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several [XML plug-ins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=xml) at your disposal

Comment: Thanks, I used this one and it works great: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in